# Setting the value to null using LINQ in list of list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I have a class

```
public class ReceiptDisplayInfo
{
public string ReceiptItemFor{get;set;}
public string ReceiptItemCategory{get;set;}
public string ReceiptItemReference{get;set;}
public string ReceiptRowCategory{get;set;}
public string ReceiptAmount{get;set;}
}
```

I have a list

```
List<List<ReceiptDisplayInfo>> dataSourceToBind ;
```

My requirement : For every List , if **ReceiptRowCategory="Payment"** , I have to set the value of **ReceiptItemForm**,**ReceiptItemCategory** to blank or null in **dataSourceToBind** .

I am doing using for loop but this is not the most appreciated approach.

Please assist me in doing using LINQ/Lambda Expression.

Comment: What have you already tried? Let's see some code or do you want us to write it for you? ;)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom : I am using for loop , which has become nested.
I want to do using lambda/linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 dataSourceToBind.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var innerList = x;
            innerList.ForEach(y =>
            {
                if (y.ReceiptRowCategory == "Payment")
                {
                    y.ReceiptItemFor = null;
                    y.ReceiptItemCategory = null;
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve this-

```
 ((from l in list
                  where l.ReceiptItemCategory == "payment"
                  select new ReceiptDisplayInfo()
                  {
                      ReceiptItemFor = null,
                      ReceiptItemCategory = null,
                      ReceiptItemReference = l.ReceiptItemReference,
                      ReceiptRowCategory = l.ReceiptRowCategory,
                      ReceiptAmount = l.ReceiptAmount
                  }).Union(from l in list
                           where l.ReceiptItemCategory != "payment"
                           select l)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess just 2 `ForEach` calls would suffice, no need to use LINQ here. However, since the transformation logic is quite complicated, I think you should extract it as a method:

```
private void SomeMethod(ReceiptDisplayInfo info) { // please name this appropriately
    if (info.ReceiptRowCategory == "Payment") {
        info.ReceiptItemForm = null;
        info.ReceiptItemCategory = null;
    }
}
```

And then,

```
dataSourceToBind.ForEach(x => x.ForEach(SomeMethod));
```